# XCTestTarget - After upgrading to Xcode 8.2 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath] returns /private/tmp

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, macos-sierra

After upgrading to macOS sierra 10.12.2 and Xcode 8.2 from OS X 10.10.2 and Xcode 6.2 `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]` returns `/private/tmp` instead of project directory. In Xcode 6.2 it returns project directory. Are there any settings which need to be set manually?

Problem is only with test target, I created a sample project and output of

`NSLog(@"currentDirectoryPath is %@",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]);` is working directory for actual target but for test target it is always `/private/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Working with currentDirectoryPath() is not your best option here (with Xcode8). Inside your test class you should use:

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] bundlePath];
```

or

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] bundleURL];
```

This will return a NSString / NSURL pointing to the install location of the bundle. For simulator builds the paths will be as follows:

- Logic Tests Targets: *$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME*
- Application Test Targets: *$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME/PlugIns/$TEST_TARGET_PRODUCT_NAME.xctest*

Knowing this you can load resources from your test bundle e.g. via

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[filename pathExtension]]
```